# Check another columns on login with default auth on Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

This is my first attempt at using a php framework, so I decided to go with Laravel 5.

But I have a problem: I want to check the user status at login, so only `enabled == 1` users get to login. I checked **AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php**, and followed some functions on **Guard.php**, but I could not understand where does it check the actual columns, and where I should place my check for the column `is_enabled`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people probably won't agree with me, but I'd make my own Auth Controller. The default one is too obscure. If you want you can remove everything that comes with laravel with `php artisan fresh`, this will remove the Auth Controller and a bunch of other things.

It is quite simple to make your own, the login method would look something like this:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    $remember = $request->get('remember') == 'on' ? true : false;

    if(\Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
        $enabled = \Auth::user()->enabled;

        if(!$enabled) {
            \Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->withMessage('User not enabled to login');
        }
    }
}
```

Check the docs for other authentication functions:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication

You can also check the user in the DB before attempting:

```
$enabled = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first()->enabled;
if($enabled && \Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
   ... redirect to logged in page.
```

Comment: Thanks, really, someone should describe the entire login process used there, so we can understand why they did it that way, and if it is the best approach for our applications...

Answer (score 0):

As per reference from [this](https://laraveldaily.com/auth-login-how-to-check-more-than-just-emailpassword/) link, let say if there is another column **approved** that need to be checked during login, then following function need to be added in loginController

```
 public function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'approved', '1');
        return $credentials;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the authenticated method in the default LoginController. This method is called whenever a user passed the configured authentication guard.

```php
  /**
   * The user has been authenticated.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @param  mixed  $user
   * @return mixed
   */
  protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
  {
      // custom logic
      if ($user->isDisabled()) {
          $logoutResponse = $this->logout($request);

          if ($logoutResponse instanceof RedirectResponse) {
              $logoutResponse->withErrors(__('users.Your account has been deactivated'));
          }

          return $logoutResponse;
      }
      // end custom logic

      return null;
  }
```

By inspecting the AuthenticatesUsers trait form Laravel, it is made clear that the return value of this method is used in an if statement so it is fine to just return null when we want the default behavior:

```php
  /**
   * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
   *
   * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
   * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
   */
  protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
  {
      $request->session()->regenerate();

      $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

      if ($response = $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())) {
          return $response;
      }

      return $request->wantsJson()
                  ? new Response('', 204)
                  : redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
  }
```